# How can I find $P(A'\cap B')$ using De Morgan's laws?

Tags: probability

$P(A'\cap B') = P(\overline{A\cup B})$ By De Morgan's laws.

I am given $P(A|B) = \frac{1}{5}$ and $P(B|A)=\frac{1}{4}$. Let $P(A\cap B)=p$

I want to find  $P(A'\cap B')$ in terms of $p$. Perhaps I don't need to use De Morgan's law in the first step ie convert to $P(\overline{A\cup B})$?

Anyway, I tried to sub it into the conditional probability formula so $P(\overline{A\cup B}) = P(\overline{A|B})\cdot P(\overline{B})$

Now I am stuck and I assume this method is not correct :(

Edit: In a previous section, I worked out that $P(A) = 4p$. That means I will need $P(A)$ to appear in my equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution without using DeMorgan's:

$$P(A' \cap B') = P(B')P(A'|B')\\
P(B') = 1 - P(B) = 1 - \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A|B)} = 1 - 5p\\
P(A'|B')=1-P(A|B') = 1-\dfrac{P(A \cap B')}{P(B')} \\ 1-\dfrac{P(B'|A)P(A)}{P(B')}=1-\dfrac{(1-P(B|A))P(A)}{P(B')}=1-\dfrac{(1-\frac{1}{4})(4p)}{1-5p}=\dfrac{1-8p}{1-5p}\\
P(A' \cap B')=1 - 5p\cdot\dfrac{1-8p}{1-5p}=\boxed{1-8p}$$

So yes, your answer is correct. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the solution:

$(′∩′)=(\overline{∪})=P(A') + P(B') - P(\overline{A\cap B}) $

$=1-4p + 1-5p - (1-p)$

$= 1-8p$, as requested

However, I still welcome alternate solutions that don't initially use the De Morgan step